# Does the ObjectContext change for each result set?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

There are a number of [examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx) showing how to use `ObjectContext` to get results from a multi-result set stored procedure when using Entity Framework.
These examples always take the `DbContext`, cast it to a `IObjectContextAdapter`, and get the `ObjectContext`, even if they did the same thing a few lines up.

Example from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx) (original comments removed to simplify and highlight my comments):

```
using (var db = new BloggingContext())
{
    db.Database.Initialize(force: false);
    var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[GetAllBlogsAndPosts]";
    try
    {
        db.Database.Connection.Open();
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        var blogs = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db)
            .ObjectContext                                              //First Time
            .Translate<Blog>(reader, "Blogs", MergeOption.AppendOnly);
        foreach (var item in blogs)
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        }

        reader.NextResult();
        var posts = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db)
            .ObjectContext                                              //Second Time
            .Translate<Post>(reader, "Posts", MergeOption.AppendOnly);

        foreach (var item in posts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Title);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        db.Database.Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

My stored procedures return many result sets, so I would like to simplify the code as much as possible by copying the reference to `ObjectContext` to a local variable, but I am not sure if doing so will cause issues.
I did find an [article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/objectcontext-vs-dbcontext/) which indicates that "Conceptually 'DbContext' is the same as 'ObjectContext'."
I have not found anything explicitly indicating the scope and lifetime of the object instance.
The documentation for [`ObjectContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.core.objects.objectcontext(v=vs.113).aspx) is a bit lacking in details.

I prefer a link to the official documentation supporting any answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DbContext` is a wrapper around an `ObjectContext`. So it contains one `ObjectContext` instance that you have access to through the `IObjectContextAdapter` interface. `IObjectContextAdapter.ObjectContext` will always return the same instance.

If you want to be absolutely sure, just check the output of

```
Console.WriteLine(((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.GetHashCode());
Console.WriteLine(((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.GetHashCode());
```

It will show the same value twice.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I am looking for documentation proving this more than tricks which show that it works for one implementation.  Documentation for `DbContext` being a wrapper around an `ObjectContext` should suffice.

Comment: It works for one implementation, but that happens to be the only implementation. In EF there's nothing else that implements `IObjectContextAdapter`. I think that the EF team simply forgot to document it (maybe because it was so obvious to them). The only official hint of documentation I can find is that Lerman & Miller in their book "DbContext" repeatedly use the phrase "*the* underlying ObjectContext" (emphasis mine). And the XML documentation of `IObjectContextAdapter.ObjectContext` itself is: "Returns the Entity Framework ObjectContext that is underlying this context."

Comment: I have gone ahead and accepted despite the fact that your code does not do a reference comparison between `ObjectContext` references and does not change the result set as requested in the original question.  At this point I am ready to move on.  Feel free to make the corrections if you want.